# How to refresh my current latitude longitube at background in android

Tags: java, android

Tell me How to referesh my current latitude and longitude in activity at every 5 min

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private TextView mLatitude, mLongitude;
private Button mNextBtn;
private Location location;

private int mInterval = 5000;
private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
private Intent intent;
Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
    mLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_long);
    mNextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);

    mNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LatLongListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    startRepeatingTask();
    mHandler = new Handler();

    /*Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // update TextView here!
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Update",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();*/

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            onLocationChanged(location);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Update",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval); // set mInterval = 300000
        }
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // called when the listener is notified with a location update from the GPS


        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLogitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLogitude);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (LocationListener) this);

            String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String longi = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            mLatitude.setText("Latitude : " + lat);
            mLongitude.setText("Logitude : " + longi);


            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
            sedt.putString("textvalue", mLatitude.getText().toString());
            sedt.putString("txtopertaive", mLongitude.getText().toString());
            sedt.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // called when the GPS provider is turned off (user turning off the GPS on the phone)
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // called when the GPS provider is turned on (user turning on the GPS on the phone)
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // called when the status of the GPS provider changes
    }


private void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Latitude and longitude set only one time. tell how to refresh every 5 min it become refresh.Please...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.currentlocationdemo, PID: 15127
                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.currentlocationdemo.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
                                                                                     at com.currentlocationdemo.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:228)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.zzo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpw.zzapp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpp.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zzasd(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zzasf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

08-24 14:50:14.124 15127-15762/com.currentlocationdemo W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in your code:

```
  Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            <call you location fetching method here || simply call location.get... methods here>

        } finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval); // set mInterval = 300000
        }
    }
 };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
       mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
       mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }
```

Comment: Hello .. am calling my onLocationChange( location) method call in try block but it not working.. please tell how to implement

Comment: onLocationChange() gets automatically called whenever your location changes. In this case try fetching locaton by: double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLogitude = location.getLongitude(); and set these value to  mLatitude and mLongitude

Comment: Tell me sir where call Runnable onCreate , onLocationChange or outside...

Comment: in onCreate() call startRepeatingTask and intialize mHandler there as well

Comment: Sir my App directly crash due to null object when am calling startRepeatingTask in onCreate...

Comment: initialise handler before calling startRepeatingTask(); instead of onLocationChanged in try block call location.getlatitude() and location.getlongitude()

Comment: No sir the application crash continuously and i get Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference error in startRepeatingTask.

Comment: Sir am uploaded logcat above

Comment: Sir my app run successfully but my lat long not set in textview ...try {
                String locLat;
                if (location != null) {
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    locLat = String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude);
                    // mLatitude.setText(locLat);
                }mLatitude.setText(locLat);

Comment: Thank you sir its sort out... Thanks for helping me ... Good day